# About logarithmic cost model and bit complexity model?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

So I heard that there are such models for finding time complexity of an algorithm as logarithmic cost model and bit complexity model. But from the information I have found in the internet, I cannot understand what operations  are taken to be constant time, but I understood that arithmetic operations are not taken to be constant time. I suppose these could be operations of reading and rewriting of the bits, but its just my guess. So what operations are taken to be constant time in logarithmic cost model and bit complexity model ? It may be that I am losing some details by thinking that these models are different from others by/only by operations taken to be constant time, if thats the case I will be grateful if you explain me the details. Also it may  be that my question is not that correct, then I will be grateful, if you help me make it better.
Thanks in advance.